# I don't get Golomb / Rice coding: It does make more bits of the input, or does it?

Tags: compression

Or, maybe, what I don't get is [unary coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_coding):

In [Golomb, or Rice, coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_coding), you split a number `N` into two parts by dividing it by another number `M` and then code the integer result of that division in unary and the remainder in binary.

In the Wikipedia [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_coding#Example), they use 42 as `N` and 10 as `M`, so we end up with a quotient `q` of 4 (in unary: 1110) and a remainder `r` of 2 (in binary 010), so that the resulting message is `1110,010`, or 8 bits (the comma can be skipped). The simple binary representation of 42 is `101010`, or 6 bits.

To me, this seems due to the unary representation of `q` which always has to be more bits than binary.

Clearly, I'm missing some important point here. What is it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The important point is that Golomb codes are not meant to be shorter than the shortest binary encoding for one particular number. Rather, by providing a specific kind of [variable-length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_code), they **reduce the *average* length per encoded value compared to fixed-width encoding, if the encoded values are from a large range, but the most common values are generally small (and hence are using only a small fraction of that range most of the time).**

As an example, if you were to transmit integers in the range from 0 to 1000, but a large majority of the actual values were in the range between 0 and 10, in a fixed-width encoding, most of the transmitted codes would have leading 0s that contain no information:

To cover all values between 0 and 1000, you need a 10-bit wide encoding in fixed-width binary. Now, as most of your values would be below 10, at least the first 6 bits of most numbers would be 0 and would carry little information.

To rectify this with Golomb codes, you split the numbers by dividing them by 10 and encoding the quotient and the remainder separately. For most values, all that would have to be transmitted is the remainder which can be encoded using 4 bits at most (if you use truncated binary for the remainder it can be less). The quotient is then transmitted in unary, which encodes as a single `0` bit for all values below 10, as `10` for 10..19, `110` for 20..29 etc.

Now, for most of your values, you have reduced the message size to 5 bits max, but you are still able to transmit all values unambigously without separators.

This comes at a rather high cost for the larger values (for example, values in the range 990..999 need 100 bits for the quotient), which is why the coding is optimal for 2-sided geometric distributions.

The long runs of 1 bits in the quotients of larger values can be addressed with subsequent run-length encoding. However, if the quotients consume too much space in the resulting message, this could indicate that other codes might be more appropriate than Golomb/Rice.

Comment: Using run-length encoding on the 1s doesn't make sense. Think about it: first you need a bit to distinguish between a run and raw bits, then you need enough bits to encode the length of the run. You could use a fixed number of bits, in which case you're using more bits than you would without any coding, or you could use a variable length encoding scheme. Such as.... Golomb coding? But then you should just be using a different value of M. Or you could use Huffman coding, but then why not just use Huffman codes for the whole thing?

Comment: Why not use Huffman codes? Two reasons: Huffman needs to transmit a whole dictionary first; Golomb-Rice only transmits the value of its single parameter. Also, Golomb-Rice is just simpler to implement. Golomb-Rice may also be a tiny bit faster as it requires no memory lookups. I haven't benchmarked any of this though.

Answer (score 2):

One difference between the Golomb coding and binary code is that binary code is not a prefix code, which is a no-go for coding strings of arbitrarily large numbers (you cannot decide if 1010101010101010 is a concatenation of 10101010 and 10101010 or something else). Hence, they are not that easily comparable.

Second, the Golomb code is optimal for geometric distribution, in this case with parameter 2^(-1/10). The probability of 42 is some 0.3 %, so you get the idea about how important is this for the length of the output string.

Comment: To clarify, binary code usually means fixed-width binary code, which is a prefix code and is unambiguous. E.g., a code with 8-bit bytes representing up to 256 values is a prefix code.